An Error during Update related to http://repository.spotify.com Ubuntu 24.04

Err:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease   The following
signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
available: NO_PUBKEY 6224F9941A8AA6D1 Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The
following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is
not available: NO_PUBKEY 6224F9941A8AA6D1
E: The repository
'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is
therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for
repository creation and user configuration details.


Should do it
curl -fsSL https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_6224F9941A8AA6D1.gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/spotify.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/spotify.gpg] http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
If you have the Spotify repo specified in a different file then remove it or you'll get a different error
